# I'm facing one issue with ngModel

Tags: angular

[image]

I'm using ngModel for two way data binding. 
but inside text fields values are printing wrongly

```
 <span><input type="text" name="name{{h.id}}"  [(ngModel)]="assessmenttype[i].heads[j].value" /></span>
                    <span>{{assessmenttype[i].heads[j].value}}</span>
```

Comment: Can you code with some sample input data. So, that we can check it and try to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

From the Stackblitz created by **Suresh Kumar Ariya** I've modified little bit code like below

**TS file**

```
assessmenttype = [{
  heads: [{
    value: 1
  }]
 },{
  heads: [{
    value: 2
  }]
 },{
  heads: [{
    value: 3
  }]
}];

h = {
  id: 1
};
```

**Template file**

```
<div *ngFor="let type of assessmenttype">
  <span>
    <input type="text" name="name{{h.id}}"  [(ngModel)]="type.heads[0].value"/>
  </span>
  <span>{{type.heads[0].value}}</span>
</div>
```

Working example is here [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8grpkt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)